# Ngx Datatable to display one row entry

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwryv.png) I would like to display all the trans types but the correlation id must only appear once. How do I achieve this from the front end?

HTML code:

```
        <ngx-datatable #tblCorrelations class="material fullscreen" [rows]="details" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="'auto'" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="50" [limit]="15" [selected]="selected" [selectionType]="'single'">
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Correlation ID" id="correlationid">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{row.correlationid}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Trans Type" id="transtype">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{row.transtype}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ngx-datatable>
```

What would my typescript code look like? Bear in mind, the correlation id is not the trans type id. This is all been pulled from the database and not hard-coded

Currently, the display repeats the correlation id and display the trans types
I want the correlation id to appear once only and all its trans types

Comment: can you please show data that coming

Comment: Hi harkesh, please see the table image

Comment: thanks, for the assistance, i found this link helpful https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-grouping.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Your details must look like this. (can be a **Class** or an **Interface**)

```
export class/Interface InterfaceName {
 correlationId: number;
 transType: string[];
}
```

In your `.ts` File, declare details as:

```
public details: InterfaceName[];
```